# AutoComplete (AutoFilter?), using jQuery delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

```
$('#container form').delegate('#addSearch', 'keyup', function(e) { 
        var tmpVAL = $('#addSearch').val();
        $('.w').each(function() {
            var tmpHTML = $(this).html();
            if (tmpHTML == tmpVAL) {
                $(this).fadeIn(250);
            } else if (tmpVAL.length < 1) {
                $(this).fadeIn(250);
            } else {
                $(this).fadeOut(250);
            }
        });
    });
```

and `#addSearch` is an `<input type="text">`.

So, my problem is that; this obviously will only return the results that are an exact match to the `tmpVAL` - How would I allow it so every letter will change the search result.

e.g.

I type `N`
it comes up with `No, Not, Nothing, Nothingness`

I type `NOT`
it comes up with `Not, Nothing, Nothingness`

Any help would be appreciated, I would imagine that it would be RegEx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, but I think that might be overkill.  You could just use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
$('#container form').delegate('#addSearch', 'keyup', function(e) {
    var tmpVAL = $('#addSearch').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.w').each(function() {
        var tmpHTML = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        if (tmpHTML.indexOf(tmpVAL) >= 0) {
            $(this).fadeIn(250);
        } else if (tmpVAL.length < 1) {
            $(this).fadeIn(250);
        } else {
            $(this).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/PRyvU/

---

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't use an `.each()`:

```
$('#container form').delegate('#addSearch', 'keyup', function(e) {
    var tmpVAL = $('#addSearch').val().toLowerCase();
    var $words = $(".w");
    var contains = function(haystack, needle) {
        return haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0;
    };

    if (tmpVAL.length < 1) {
        $words.fadeIn(250);
    }
    else {
        $words.filter(function() {
            return !contains($(this).html().toLowerCase(), tmpVAL);      
        }).fadeOut(250);
        $words.filter(function() {
            return contains($(this).html().toLowerCase(), tmpVAL);
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/EyJ6b/

Comment: the problem with theese is that it match also word not starting with typed value example http://jsfiddle.net/PRyvU/3/ type n it match **nothing** but also **anonymous**

Answer (score 4):

> - **DEMO** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/autocomplete-autofilter-using-jquery-delegate

```
$(function() {
    $('#container form').delegate('#addSearch', 'keyup', function(e) {
        var tmpVAL = $('#addSearch').val();
        $('.w').each(function() {
            var tmpHTML = $(this).text();
            var subSection = tmpHTML.substring(tmpVAL.length, 0);
            if (subSection == tmpVAL && tmpVAL != '' ) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```